# how can i recv information from server? python socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

i can recv info from client but i dont know how to recv it from server.

"i think in line 15 i need to change "socket" to somethong"
it must be that type: 'socket.socket'

client:

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # AF_INET = IP, SOCK_STREAM = TCP
client.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1002))  # 127.0.0.1

while True:
    command = input('>>>')
    if command == 'stop':
        exit()
    command = command.encode('utf-8')
    client.send(command)

    get = socket.recv(2048)
    get = get.decode('utf-8')
    print('recieve',get)
```

server:

```
import socket
import subprocess

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # AF_INET = IP, SOCK_STREAM = TCP
server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 1002))  # 127.0.0.1
server.listen()

client_socket, client_address = server.accept()

print(type(client_socket))

while True:
    get = client_socket.recv(2048)
    get = get.decode('utf-8')
    print('recieve',get)

    output = subprocess.check_output(get, shell=True)


    client_socket.send(output)
```

output from client:

```
File "C:\Users\rusla\Desktop\client.py", line 15, in <module>
  get = socket.recv(1024)
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'recv'
```

Comment: i just need to change 'socket' in line 15 for something. (but i dont know to what)

Comment: `recv` works the same way whether called from a server or a client. You haven't mentioned what problem you're having. Most likely, whatever problem the problem is, we'll need to see the server code as well to help diagnose it.

Comment: No code in comments please, edit your question and put the code in your question.

Comment: Change `socket.recv(2048)` to `client.recv(2048)` in the client.  Voting to close as typo.  Also realize that TCP is a streaming protocol.  You get the bytes in the same order but not necessarily with the same data breaks.  `recv(2048)` will receive 1-2048 bytes, or zero if the connection is closed.  In this simple case it will likely work but normally you need to treat a socket like a file.  If you write lines to a file without newlines, how would you tell where one line ends and another begins?